# How to Include-guard when using multiple headers on a main.cpp?

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ in a course, using Visual Studio 2013, and I have an issue with include-guards on my `main.cpp`. I can't use either `class` or `#pragma once` (though they work) due to conditions my professor said.

If I only use `Coordinates` and `Line`, and I use in `main.cpp` the `#include Line.h` (which get code from both `Line` and `Coordinates`), this works ok, but when I add `Rectangle` and `Triangle` (both have `#include "Line.h"`), then it throws the "already defined" `error LNK2005` several times.

Is there something missing?

This is my code:

Coordinates.h

```
#ifndef Coordinates
#define Coordinates
//Code declaration. Other headers have similar declaration
struct CoordinatesType { double x, y; } coordinates;
void setCoordinates(double x, double y);
CoordinatesType getCoordinates();
#endif
```

Coordinates.cpp

```
#include "Coordinates.h"
//Code implementation
```

Line.h

```
#ifndef Line
#define Line
#include "Coordinates.h"
//Code declaration
#endif
```

Line.cpp

```
#include "Line.h"
#include <math.h>
//Code implementation
```

Rectangle.h

```
#ifndef Rectangle
#define Rectangle
#include "Line.h"
//Code declaration
#endif
```

Rectangle.cpp

```
#include "Rectangle.h"
//Code implementation
```

Triangle.h

```
#ifndef Triangle
#define Triangle
#include "Line.h"
//Code declaration
#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Triangle.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"
int main(){
    //Do stuff here.
}
```

If you need me to add the implementation and declaration codes, let me know, but I feel like it has to do with the include-guard.

EDIT: I'll add code in the Coordinate header so you can get an idea of what I'm doing and to avoid consuming a lot of space in the post. Remember, I can't use `class Coordinates{}` due to my professor's restriction to not use it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: How you class has been named ? `Line` as the include guards ?

Comment: Your professor is prohibiting you from using forward declarations? What is he/she teaching you, "how not to do it"??

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's because we "didn't learn classes yet", and "pragma once is not a standard". I searched how to apply include-guards and pragma once, and in the explanations, classes were developed, so when I showed it to my teacher, he said "don't use classes because we haven't learned them yet".

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't use the `class Line {}`, if that's what you're asking, due to what I explained to @LightnessRacesInOrbit

Comment: @MayerM: I'm sorry to hear that. In my school, having the initiative to actually submit the proper solution that would be used in real life was rewarded, not discarded. Perhaps your professor hasn't learnt classes yet.

Comment: @MayerM: You mean `class Line;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is a linker error, not a compiler error.

*Header guards do nothing for the linker.*

You have successfully guarded against multiple declarations of things within the same translation unit, but you have not guarded against multiple definitions of things across your whole program.

The way to guard against that is to, well, not do that. There should be no non-inline, non-template definitions of anything in your header if you want to include it into multiple source files.

Here, you declare a type `CoordinatesType`, and create an object of that type:

```
struct CoordinatesType { double x, y; } coordinates;
```

Don't do that! Create an instance of `CoordinatesType` only in a source file, not in a header. Otherwise, every source file that includes this header (directly or indirectly) will get its own `coordinates` object and your linker complains about the name collision.

The code should be:

```
struct CoordinatesType { double x, y; };
```

Then, either `coordinates` in the *one* source file in which you wish to use the object… or `extern` on its declaration in a header. There are better approaches but I shan't enumerate them all here since this topic has been covered to death on SO already. Furthermore, your C++ book will have an explanation.

But the long and short of it is that this has nothing to do with header guards.

Comment: Of course, since you did not follow instructions and present your [MCVE], I cannot tell you specifically what you did wrong.

Comment: Ok. I'll add the entire code now. Thanks for answering

Comment: @MayerM: Who told you to "add the entire code?" Present your [MCVE]!! You ... do have one, right?

Comment: Nevermind. I didn't get what you meant until you updated. Thanks, now I get what I did wrong.

Comment: @MayerM: Excellent

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, your problem has nothing to do with include-guards.

Your problem is in this line:

```
struct CoordinatesType { double x, y; } coordinates;
```

While the declaration of the struct

```
struct CoordinatesType { double x, y; };
```

may appear in multiple .cpp files, as long as it is identical (it is, since you include the same header-file), you also define a variable

```
CoordinatesType coordinates;
```

in the same line. Since a definition is only allowed once, your linker complains.

If you really need a global variable of that type (check if you really need one, as it might not be necessary), change your header to a declaration:

```
struct CoordinatesType { double x, y; };
extern CoordinatesType coordinates;
```

and use a definition

```
CoordinatesType coordinates;
```

in *exactly one* cpp-file.

Note that the error didn't happen when only including Line and Coordinates, because your include-guards work *and you only include the headers in a single .cpp file*

Comment: Yeah, you beat me with your edit by a few seconds ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I understand what I did wrong, and I fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Coordinates.h doesn't have any include guard.

When you include it multiple times, it defines Coordinates only once, but the rest of the file is included multiple times.

Put the #endif in the right place.

PS. The identifiers used in the include guards should be something that is never, ever used elsewhere by coincidence. I wouldn't be surprised if someone tried to use a variable named Line or Triangle. And since you #define those, that will lead to very unexpected errors. Use something like #define LineHeader_Included__ .

Comment: Eh? It does have an include guard, and the `#endif` is in the right place.